# Why would you =delete implicitly deleted default constructors and what is the point?

Tags: c++, clang

I am trying to delete all the copy/move ctor/assignment operators that are implicitly provided, but why am i still able to explicitly delete the default ctor that was supposed to be implicitly deleted?

I have tried =default-ing all the copy/move ctor/assignment operators implicitly provided only to then be told to actually =delete rather than =default. If my understanding of implicit/explicit is correct, the default ctor should be implicitly deleted if the user provides an explicit copy ctor.

I have the following class:

```
class A {
public:
   A() =delete;       
   A(const A&):...{;} --> my explicitly defined copy ctor
   ...
}
```

I expected the compiler to tell me that i cant `=delete` an implicitly deleted default ctor, but that is not the case. I am using clang8 to complile.

Comment: What would be the problem with telling the compiler you want to delete something it will delete anyways?

Comment: I have a lot of base classes and child classes and when dealing with inheritance and const member variables, i am trying to delete what is not already deleted with the purpose of establishing a norm to impose restrictions. I don't want the next programmer to have to look up the inheritance chain to try and figure out what is not already implicitly deleted.

Comment: If the compiler does not generate a function, it won't be used as a possible match.  If you explicitly `=delete` a function, it may still be considered as a possible best match, and then the compiler will error saying the function has been deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can delete everything you want, fully independent if it was already (implicit) deleted or not.

It is a good idea to show that you did not want to have a default generated function like operators or constructors and "mark" them as deleted. This helps for clarification of the interface!

But: You still can instantiate your class even if you delete the constructor(s)!

```
class A { 
    public:
        A() =delete;
        A(int) = delete;

        int a;

        void Print() const { std::cout << a << std::endl; }
};  

int main()
{   
    A a{42};
    a.Print();
}
```

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

From you comment:

> I don't want the next programmer to have to look up the inheritance chain to try and figure out what is not already implicitly deleted.

As long as you define a single constructor and do not explicit enable using of base constructors with:

```
 using X::X;
```

nobody has the need of looking to the base class constructors at all. As said: It is a good idea to mark "unwanted" methods as `delete` but there are cases, where that did not help in any case as shown above!

Comment: Interesting, after reading your answer I went back and removed  the initialization list from the copy ctor and the compiler complained that i am deleting a deleted constructor. But if i leave the copy ctor with an initialization list, the compiler will provide a default ctor and i get no complaints when i try to delete the default ctor. I am not sure why it is this way, is this intended behavior from the compiler? hmmm

Comment: @AlexB: There are a (endless) list of discussions around the "delete" thing from c++11 to c++20. And especially about aggregates that can be instantiated with all constructors beeing deleted is a very "nice" feature. I can't tell you what the iso committee really think what is "intended behavior" here ;) I can only point you to the standard which is quite clear but not not very intuitive.

Comment: it's a quite foggy subject, i hope the standard becomes more intuitive so i don't have to spend hours looking though stackoverflow/c++coreGuide for some explanation :)